# Mysql Select Query without PHP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written following select query which returns the required records.I know how to code this in PHP. I am wondering if it is possible in one single select mysql query

```
SELECT annual_end_date
    ,email
    ,expiry_id
    ,status
    ,verify
    ,email
    ,password
FROM Users
WHERE email = 'test@test.com'
    AND password = 'password'
```

On the same table I would also like to check (psuedo code PHP below), return expiry_id=0 records and `annual_end_date` is a `date` Column is less `then  current date`

```
If expiry_id='0' THEN
    check annual_end_date column 
    If annual_end_date is less then the current date
```

If expiry_id is not equal to '0' it should check `subscription table` and compare `pay_end_date` column

```
If expiry_id!='0' 
    check pay_end_date column in subscription table 
    If pay_end_date is less then the current date then show records
```

Subscription table has just one field `pay_end_date` with is a `date column`

Comment: You can possibly use mysql statement `Left Join`, `Right Join`, or `Join` or do a Multi dimensional statement.

Comment: You don't have Subscription table in here at all So we don't know how Subscription applies to your data.

Comment: @CayceK Subscription table has just one field pay_end_date with is a date column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this to your query...

```
 AND (  ( expiry_id='0' AND annual_end_date < DATE(NOW()) )
     OR ( expiry_id<>'0' AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                                        FROM subscription s
                                       WHERE s.user_id = Users.user_id -- ?
                                         AND s.pay_end_date < DATE(NOW())
                                    )
        )
     )
```

The specification says to check the "subscription table", but no indication is given about the relationship between `subscription` and `Users`. The subquery is based on a guess about the foreign key column in subscription, and the referenced column in `Users`.

Comment: There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result. This was only an example intended to illustrate one possible pattern. It's likely that there are other approaches that would give better performance.